# Are there any simple libev/libevent implementations supporting websockets?

Tags: c, websocket, libevent, libev

I am looking for an echo server example using libev or libevent that accepts websocket connections: a websocket client connects, sends a message and receives it back. SSL websockets should also be supported. Is there such thing available? If not, what's the most minimal websocket C library that can be plugged into a libev or libevent echo examples?

Comment: https://github.com/tailhook/libwebsite

Comment: Libwebsockets is a lightweight pure C library: https://libwebsockets.org